# Can a class in python behave like a specified class based on a passed parameter?

Tags: python

I have an abstract base class (called `Shape` below).  And I derive a couple classes from it (`Circle` and `Square` below).

I would like to create a "dispatching class" (called `MagicShape` below) so that when I instantiate a new object of this new class, it magically becomes one of the derived classes above based on a passed parameter.

I.e. if `Circle` and `Square` both get initialized with 2 parameters, I want `MagicShape` to take 3 parameters at instantiation so that the first parameter would either be the string `circle` or the string `square` and would result in creating either a `Circle` or `Square` with the subsequently specified parameters.

So for specifics, I have:

```
from numpy import pi as PI

class Shape(object):
    def __init__(self, color, size):
        self.color=color
        self.size = size

    def describe(self):
        return 'I am a {color:s} {kind:s} of size {size:0.1f}'.format(color=self.color, 
                                                                      kind=self.kind,
                                                                      size=self.size)

class Circle(Shape):
    def __init__(self, color, size):
        self.kind = 'circle'
        super(Circle, self).__init__(color, size)

    def area(self):
        return PI * self.size * self.size

class Square(Shape):
    def __init__(self, color, size):
        self.kind = 'square'
        super(Square, self).__init__(color, size)

    def area(self):
        return self.size * self.size
```

And I would like to have something like:

```
class MagicShape(???):
    def __init__(self, kind, color, size):
        # what goes in here?
```

So that when I run `ms = MagicShape('circle', 'red', 3)`, `ms` is a `Circle` but when I run `ms = MagicShape('square', 'blue', 2)`, `ms` is a `Square`.

I know that I could do something like this:

```
def make_shape(kind, color, size):
    if 'circle'==kind:
        return Circle(color, size)
    elif 'square'==kind:
        return Square(color, size)
    else:
        raise ValueError
```

and do the "dispatching" via function.  But somehow this felt like it should be doable with classes.  Can someone set me straight?

Comment: Why not make a function, rather than a class? Then just pick the appropriate class from a dictionary `{'circle': Circle, ...}` and instantiate and return it.

Comment: That's what I have coded up at the moment, actually.  I just thought somehow it seemed like this *should* be a class that can act a bit chameleon-y.  Guess just thought it should be intuitively possible.  No real need other than aesthetics.

Comment: Your solution with a factory function is a fine way to do it.  There's no reason to force yourself to do it with a class when it works fine as a function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could just use a function, no class required:

```
shapes = {shape.__name__.lower(): shape 
          for shape in Shape.__subclasses__()}

def MagicShape(kind, color, size):
    try:
        return shapes[kind](color, size)
    except KeyError:
        raise ValueError(kind)
```

The [`class.__subclasses__()` method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=__subclasses__#class.__subclasses__) here returns all subclasses of `Shape`, making for a quick and handy way to build a map from `kind` string to class.

Remember that creating a class is *just another call*. There is no difference between:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, arg1, arg2):
        pass
```

and

```
def Foo(arg1, arg2):
    return something_that_is_an_instance
```

from the caller's point of view; they'd just use:

```
result = Foo(value1, value2)
```

for both the class and the function.

Comment: Nothing against this solution from a practical point of view.  (I think I even included a slightly-less-fancy version of this very function in my question.)  I was curious if there was a way to get it done so that creating the new object could be done *just like* regular old object instantiation.  I guess it's a silly goal.  But its what I was after.

Comment: @8one6: but creating a *regular* object is **just another call**. From an API perspective, calling my function vs. your class would look *exactly the same*.

Comment: Kudos for mentioning `class.__subclasses__()` !

Comment: Totally understood.  I think it's funny that you used `CamelCase` for your `MagicShape` function.  Part of me just wanted to instantiate these objects  in a way that looked consistent with other object instatiation, but I felt like I hadn't earned `CamelCase` if all I was doing was calling a dispatching function as you did above (and I did in my question).  I figured the style police would yell and scream.

Comment: @8one6: the style police would yell and scream, indeed. I used CamelCase on purpose here to make a point, to show that you could easily use a function and hide the fact that it is just a factory *function* rather than a class.

Comment: What do you think about putting the `shapes = {...}` line into the fuction body so that it gets re-called on every construction?  Con: slows things down.  Pro: if you create new derived classes later on they will be "picked up" automatically and included in the dispatching function.

Comment: @8one6 In that later case, a simple linear search of the subclass inside `MagicShape` will perform better that building a dictionary on each call.

Comment: @SylvainLeroux...please explain.

Comment: @8one6: creating the dictionary each time is a loop that takes N steps; all to get one class picked out and returned. Each time. You may as well just loop over `class.__subclasses__` until you find the matching class.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the factory pattern, this example does almost exactly what you are asking:
http://python-3-patterns-idioms-test.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Factory.html

Answer (score 0):

The thing you'd probably want to do (factory/dispatch function) is already outlined in other answers/comments here, but if you actually wanted to return a different class instance and make it look like you're only making a `MagicClass`, you could do something fancy/awful with the `__new__` method, like so:

```
class MagicClass(object):
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs): 
        # if args[whatever] == 'square': return Square(*args, **kwargs)
```

...or something like that. It's not good practice, but it *is* doable.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use a factory method.  Pretty much just as you did, but you can pull it under your super Shape class.

```
from numpy import pi as PI

class Shape(object):
    #we'll use this below factory method to return the correct subclass:
    @classmethod
    def getShape(self,kind,color,size):
        if 'circle'==kind:
            return Circle(color, size)
        elif 'square'==kind:
            return Square(color, size)
        else:
           raise ValueError

    def __init__(self, color, size):
        self.color=color
        self.size = size

    def describe(self):
        return 'I am a {color:s} {kind:s} of size {size:0.1f}'.format(color=self.color, 
                                                                      kind=self.kind,
                                                                      size=self.size)

class Circle(Shape):
    def __init__(self, color, size):
        self.kind = 'circle'
        super(Circle, self).__init__(color, size)

    def area(self):
        return PI * self.size * self.size

class Square(Shape):
    def __init__(self, color, size):
        self.kind = 'square'
        super(Square, self).__init__(color, size)

    def area(self):
        return self.size * self.size
```